# How to generate HTML with JS and let Google Detect it

Tags: javascript, html, dynamic, seo

I have a bunch of arrays that generate some random text (the arrays are filled with data pulled out from a database using AJAX), is there any way for Google or any other Search Engine to be able to detect this content and get indexed?

Comment: No. Search engines do not execute JavaScript.

Comment: @Kolink: That's [not true](https://www.google.com/search?q=googlebot%20javascript).

Comment: @josh3736 I want the search engine to index my content.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://developers.google.com/webmasters/ajax-crawling/

Use hashbang urls for Google, and use [PhantomJS](http://phantomjs.org/) to get snapshots of the rendered DOM and serve the rendered page.

Something like https://github.com/ekesken/crawlajax might help.

Answer (score 1):

You're going to need to generate this content `Server-side` - using PHP or some other server side language. The code needs to be part of the page before it loads on the client's machine.

Answer (score 0):

Javascript generated content can't be indexed : robots don't have javascript, they simply don't see this content.

Answer (score 0):

As a lot of search engines focus on quality content (especially with recent update e.g. Google), I think randomly generated content would actually go against the guidelines provided by the search engines

http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.co.uk/2011/05/more-guidance-on-building-high-quality.html

Answer (score 0):

Well, not really.
The only solution I can think of right away is to do this server side using languages like Node.JS or PHP.

Here's how you'd do it in PHP:

```
$array = array("value 1", "value 2", "value 3", "value 4", "value 5");
echo array_rand($array, 1);
```